# не работает форма обратной связи на open server

Tags: php, html

тестирую на open server.
не приходит сообщение во вкладку "просмотр логов"

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST["send"])){
        $from = htmlspecialchars ($_POST["from"]);
        $subject = htmlspecialchars ($_POST["subject"]);
        $message = htmlspecialchars ($_POST["message"]);
        $_SESSION["from"] = $from;
        $_SESSION["message"] = $message;
        $_SESSION["subject"] = $subject;
        $error_from = "";
        $error_message = "";
        $error_subject = "";
        if($from == "" || !preg_match ("/@/", $from) ){
            $error_from = "введите корректный email";
            $error = true;
        }
        if(strlen($subject) == 0){
            $error_subject = "введите тему";
            $error = true;
        }
        if(strlen($message) == 0){
            $error_message = "введите сообщение";
            $error = true;
        }
        if(!$error){
            $subject = "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=";
            $headers = "From: $from\r\nRreply-to: $from\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
            mail($subject, $message, $headers);
            exit;
        }
    }   
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>connect</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="connect.css"/>
    <!--<meta charset="UTF-8"/> -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contect-wrapper">
        <form name="feedback" action="" method="post">
            <div class="inputs">
                <p>от кого: <input type = "text" name = "subject"/><span style="color:red"><?php echo $error_subject ?> </span></p>
                <p>тема: <input type = "text" name = "subject"/><span style="color:red"><?php echo $error_subject ?> </span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="main-message">
                <p>сообщение: </p>
                <textarea name="message"></textarea><span style="color:red"><?php echo $error_message ?> </span>
            </div>
            <input class="button" type="submit" name="send" value="отправить" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: что пишет в лог ? у вас отправка происходит если $error = false
а если true вы не чего не выводите

Comment: и у вас переменная $error не определена, то есть даже если у вас пройдена вся валидация, то условие if(!$error) все ровно не выполниться

Comment: спасибо, даже не заметил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["send"])){
    $from = htmlspecialchars ($_POST["from"]);
    $subject = htmlspecialchars ($_POST["subject"]);
    $message = htmlspecialchars ($_POST["message"]);
    $_SESSION["from"] = $from;
    $_SESSION["message"] = $message;
    $_SESSION["subject"] = $subject;
    $error = false;
    $error_from = "";
    $error_message = "";
    $error_subject = "";
    if($from == "" || !preg_match ("/@/", $from) ){
        $error_from = "введите корректный email";
        $error = true;
    }
    if(strlen($subject) == 0){
        $error_subject = "введите тему";
        $error = true;
    }
    if(strlen($message) == 0){
        $error_message = "введите сообщение";
        $error = true;
    }
    if(!$error){
        $subject = "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=";
        $headers = "From: $from\r\nRreply-to: $from\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        mail($subject, $message, $headers);
        exit;
    }
}
```